Does setState function changes its reference on render in React?
In React or JS due to closure the varaibles which are outside the function and are accessed, function keeps an reference to them. And on render the state variable changes its reference making the one captured by the function as invalid. But what about the function 'setState' ? Does it also changes its reference after each render ?
In the below component setCount is being called by the eventListener and on the render address of setCount should be changed. And the old one given as reference to the scrollHandler should not update the UI. But it is not happening ?
I know that by using the count inside the scrollHandler ( setCount(count) ) refernce of count will be captured. But why not of setCount ?
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import './Navbar.css';
import logo from '../../assets/logo.png'
const Navbar = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  console.log("Count is " + count);
  useEffect(() => {
      const scrollHandler = () => {
          console.log("Handler is called");
          setCount((count) => count + 1);
      }
      window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler);
  }, [])
  return (
     <></>
  )
}
export default Navbar


If it doesn't change reference then how can it change the current count ( defined on render ) and older count ( captured by scrollHandler ) depending on if we use setCount(count + 1) or setCount ((count) => count + 1)).
I've read several articles for the problems arising due to closures, but all of them focus on the state variable, and I couldn't find any which explains about the setState function.

The useState hook updater function is a stable reference, which is why the highly recommended eslint-plugin-react-hooks plugin doesn't flag the state updater functions, i.e. setCount, as missing dependencies. In other words, React already knows it is a stable reference that doesn't change render cycle to render cycle.
But if it was an unstable reference and you were using the eslint-plugin-react-hooks plugin then you'd receive a warning about setCount being a missing dependency and that you should memoize it yourself, just like as any other external callback dependency.
Additional Note
Don't forget to cleanup event subscriptions!
useEffect(() => {
  const scrollHandler = () => {
    console.log("Handler is called");
    setCount((count) => count + 1);
  };

  window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler, true);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler, true);
  };
}, [])


So, can I say that 'setCount' always has the same reference, but the count changes its reference on each render ? And, if the eventListener makes a closure for the count and re-render occurs , in this case we are having two count references, one newly created and other one which is captured by eventListener. Which count will be affected by setCount function and why ?

@RonakJain Yes, setCount will always be the same reference, but count is a primitive number type, which will always be equal by value instead of by reference, but yes, the general gist is that with non-primitives they would not be shallow reference equal. You are using a functional state update, so there is no closure over the count state in the event listener callback. No count state will be affected. The functional update is passed the current state and it returns the next state value.
